# AS3 try catch is heavy?

Tags: actionscript-3, performance, coding-style, try-catch

Why using try catch is bad for application performance?
I'm not saying about using try catch 100 times. Actually when i use it thousands of time.
Is it really causes problems for performance?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking for using exceptions as general practices, keep in mind exceptions are 'exceptional'. As long as you use them for what they are meant for - handling events that shouldn't be happening, it should be fine.

So, do not try to use Exceptions for branching, implementing sub-routines or passing information around, and it shouldn't have an impact on performance. Even if it is heavy, it is meant to be called once in a long, long while. Or preferably, never at all.

Comment: i have chat application written in AS3, every 1.5 second i call webservice for new messages. Chat is the part of game, there are many locations based on one class that is responsable for database iteraction. For this reason i use same class in chat. Each time when i call webservice url, on response i've put try catch statement in order to catch invalid json if there appears problem in php file. So, in chat, each call for fresh messages, passes through try catch statement. I think it's bad idea? :)

Comment: Try is just an assert, it is not the part that hog resources. It's the throw part that is expensive, as the interpreter must unravel the stack to 'rise' the exception, looking for a catch statement to pass the exception to.

Answer (score 4):

try/catch (as anonymous function) will create an Activation object that will use more memory and will not use register for your local variable.
So using it will eat memory and slow down the **whole function** using it.

You can look at the [avm2 performance PDF](http://onflex.org/ACDS/AS3TuningInsideAVM2JIT.pdf) for example it didn't talk about try/catch but you can look at method closure chapter where anonymous function are described and use same mecanism for try/catch.

Comment: that link no longer goes to the referenced documentation.

Comment: A catch will slow down a method even if it not used unless it's an empty catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a try and catch statement is very slow (in comparison to other operations) when it *catches* an error. Obviously it has its purpose but never rely on on a try and catch statement for logic control. It is there for protection of code where an error has a chance of occurring (like file IO).